# How can I share what I know about but nobody hasn't asked that?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have somethings like a few formulas in mathematics (especially sequences and series) that I'd like to share them with all the people in the site and encourage others to do so but until now nobody hasn't asked something that is relevant to the contents of my findings. I want to know how can I post those formulas in the site?

I know, a similar question has been asked before but I'm asking that I have somethings (just to see) and it's a bit difficult to make a question for somethings like that without getting tons of dislikes. My point is that for showing knowledge like that, you can't just ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking), you're free to ask a question and answer it yourself, if you think the question and the answer would be interesting to the community.  There's even a checkbox on the "Ask Question" page that you can check to let you submit an answer together with your question.

That said, please do take a moment to consider whether the community really *will* find your discoveries as interesting as you yourself consider them to be.  While *good*, interesting self-answered questions can easily get a lot of upvotes, poorly thought-out self-answered question can also easily get heavily downvoted, especially if your question comes across as just soapboxing or self-promotion.

In particular, and without intending to unduly discourage you by any means, if it *does* happen that your self-answered question is poorly received, please take that as useful feedback.  It can be often hard to judge whether things that seem very interesting or important to oneself really are as interesting to the rest of the community.  Voting is how you get feedback on that.

Also note that some things are simply not well suited for the Q&A format used here on Stack Exchange.  If you'd like to share something that is not easily phrased as an answer to a question, consider, say, starting a blog to share your thoughts instead.